# Generate cURL command of swagger

Tags: curl, swagger, swagger-ui

We have an API documentation generated by swagger [running here](http://apiomat.org/apidocs) and I asked myself how to let swagger generate an additional curl command line example for the current endpoint/method. Is that possible without hacking into skala?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simply update your swagger-ui bundle and curl commands section will show up by default

Comment: are you able to say which version of the swagger-ui include curl?

Comment: @bigtv I think it is there since v2.0, as seen from [this PR](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/pull/1315)